# Prevent leaflet zoom animation within a $timeout

Tags: javascript, leaflet

There is an animation that occurs when my leaflet image is loaded.  I have inserted a `$timeout` function to slow it down to see if that would help, but it didn't fix the issue.  It may be an issue with the `imageOverlay` or and issue with `setMaxBounds`.  It could either be a timing issue or something is in the wrong place.  Any thoughts?

```
var loadImageMap = function (callback) {
      // dimensions of the image
      getBase64Image($scope.selectedFloorplan, function (image) {
        $scope.imageUrl = image;

        getImageSize($scope.imageUrl, function () {
          $scope.imageW = this.width;
          $scope.imageH = this.height;

          // create the image map
          var initialZoom = 5;
          $scope.mapRef = L.map('imageMap', {
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 10,
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: initialZoom,
            crs: L.CRS.Simple
          });

          // calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
          var southWest = $scope.mapRef.unproject([0, $scope.imageH], initialZoom);
          var northEast = $scope.mapRef.unproject([$scope.imageW, 0], initialZoom);
          var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

          // add the image overlay,
          // so that it covers the entire map
          L.imageOverlay($scope.imageUrl, bounds).addTo($scope.mapRef);

          // tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
          $scope.mapRef.setMaxBounds(bounds);

          $timeout(function () {
            // set fit-to-image zoom level
            var zoomOut = initialZoom - (getMaxZoom() - 2);
            $scope.mapRef.setZoom(zoomOut, {animate: false});

            // set minimum zoom to the fit-to-image level
            $scope.mapRef.options.minZoom = zoomOut;

            // load cameras after the imageOverlay has been added
            callback();                    
          }, 250);
        });
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.  The `$timeout` function that holds `var zoomOut` is in the correct place.  The problem is that I was setting the `imageOverlay` to early. If you move `L.imageOverlay($scope.imageUrl, bounds).addTo($scope.mapRef);` into the `$timeout` function it will set the zoom and then set the `imageOverlay` which will load the image without the animation.  You want the bounds and the zoom level to be set first then after that the `imageOverlay`.  That is if you want the image to load without an animation and to be centered properly.

```
$timeout(function () {
    // set fit-to-image zoom level
    var zoomOut = initialZoom - (getMaxZoom() - 2);
    $scope.mapRef.setZoom(zoomOut, {animate: false});

    // set minimum zoom to the fit-to-image level
    $scope.mapRef.options.minZoom = zoomOut;

    // add the image overlay,
    // so that it covers the entire map
    L.imageOverlay($scope.imageUrl, bounds).addTo($scope.mapRef);

    // load cameras after the imageOverlay has been added
    callback();

    }, 250);
```